# Grab filename for manipulation

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

Similar to my request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368840/get-and-use-current-folder-name-inside-a-batch-file/26369012?noredirect=1#comment41398022_26369012)

I'm looking for a way to take the name of a numbered file and use it else where in a batch script.

For example, in a folder there would be a file named 159 and I would need `cmd.exe` to grab that number '159' so that I can do some arithmetic with it (eg. `159 + %p%`, `159<%p%` etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's only one (quoting: "a file") file:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b') do @set name=%%a
```

will set the variable `name` to the full name of that file inside a batch script.

It loops through the command output (`dir /b`).

Comment: Yes there is only one file in the folder and your command works like a charm. Intergrated into my batch file successfully, Thank You